# Program to remove all instances of a character from a phrase is only removing some instances

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I'm creating a program to remove all instances of a character from a given phrase, and I am only allowed to use the following String methods: length, concat, +, charAt, substring, and equals (or equalsIgnoreCase). However, when I run the program, it only removes some instances of the character.

I thought it was because the indices could have gone out of bounds, so I adjusted the for loop to run as long as i < userString.length() - 1, but the program is still only removing two instances of the character. Code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userString = "goooo dawwwwgs";
        String charToRemove = "";

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
        System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
        charToRemove = sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < userString.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (userString.substring(i, i+1).equals(charToRemove))
            {
                userString = userString.substring(0, i) + userString.substring(i + 1);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("The new sentence is: " + userString);           
    }
}
```

Comment: you are changing the string while you are running on it, probably that is what makes the problems (just think of it - you are cutting out part of the string - and keeping the index at the same place, so you are skipping some letters that moved backwards

Comment: thank you! I'll keep that in mind and try and make changes

Comment: So if you remove the letter _o_ (for example) from the string _goooo dawwwwgs_, should the result be: _g dawwwwgs_ ?

Comment: You should utilize the _charAt_ method here, considering your _sub-strings_ are single characters.

Comment: Off-topic: You might want to change `sc.nextLine()` to `sc.next()`

Comment: By the way, for future reference, for questions of this type, it is good to show one or more  examples of input (✔), expected output (✗), and actual output (✗).

Answer (score 0):

> *"... However, when I run the program, it only removes some instances of the character. ..."*

Decrement *i* whenever the *String* is parsed.

```java
if (userString.substring(i, i+1).equals(charToRemove))
{
    userString = userString.substring(0, i) + userString.substring(i + 1);
    i--;
}
```

Additionally, the *loop* should be conditional to *i < userString.length()*, and not *i < userString.length() - 1*.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userString = "goooo dawwwwgs";
String charToRemove = "";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
charToRemove = sc.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++)
{
    if (userString.substring(i, i+1).equals(charToRemove))
    {
        userString = userString.substring(0, i) + userString.substring(i + 1);
        i--;
    }
}

System.out.println("The new sentence is: " + userString);
```

Output

```
Enter the character to remove
o
The new sentence is: g dawwwwgs
```

```
Enter the character to remove
w
The new sentence is: goooo dags
```

Here is a re-factor, for reference.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = "goooo dawwwwgs";
System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
char c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
        s = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1);
        i--;
    }
System.out.println("The new sentence is: " + s);
```

Alternately, just create a new *String*.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = "goooo dawwwwgs", ns = "";
System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
char c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0), nc;
for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++)
    if ((nc = s.charAt(i)) != c) ns += nc;
System.out.println("The new sentence is: " + ns);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I prefer `charToRemove` actually be a `char`. You could use something like `char charToRemove = sc.next().charAt (0)`

In this answer, I'm suggesting *4* solutions. The easiest one is #4. But, since you are a new student, I would like you to be exposed to the thinking behind all 4.

As was mentioned in the comments, a problem results because the index advances as the string is altered. The shift and advancement causes some characters to be missed.

**1)** You are not allowed to use the `indexOf` methods in the [`String` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html). But, under the constraints imposed by your teacher, are you allowed to code your own?

```
    while ( (i = myIndexOf (userString, charToRemove) >= 0) { ...
```

You would create `public static int myIndexOf` method to be similar to one of the index methods in `String`.

**2)** Run the `for` loop backwards. That way, for each value of `i`, it will be confirmed that no occurrences of `charToRemove` occur in `userString` *after* index `i`.

```
public static String removeCharA (String source, char toDelete) { 
        
        for (int i = source.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            if (source.charAt(i) == toDelete) {
               source =  source.substring (0, i) 
                       + source.substring (i + 1);
            }
        }        
        return source;
    }
```

**3)** Use another `String` in your code. It will initially be empty, i.e. `String result = ""; // empty String`. As you go through your loop, each character in `userString` that is *not* equal to `characterToRemove`, copy the indexed character from `userString` to `result` using the `+` String concatenation operator.

**4)** Delay advancing the index when it is discovered to point to one of the characters to be deleted. One way to do that is to subtract one from the index, as in a previous answer. <editorial / opinion> But, I don't like changing the value of a `for` loop index within the block controlled by the loop. I regard that as poor style, prone to being associated with bugs. <end editorial / opinion>.  So, another way to do this is to use a nested loop. Note that solution **1)** does this. There is the `while` loop, and another loop inside `myIndexOf`.

However, there is a much easier way to implement the 2nd loop:

*You can fix your code by changing a single word:*

-- Change the `if` to `while`.

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, you forgot to do `i--` every time when you remove one character from the given string:

```java
public static String removeCharacters(String str, char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
            str = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Actually, you can replace the snippet with inline string method with a bit better performance:

```java
public static String removeCharacters(String str, char ch) {
    return str.replace(String.valueOf(ch), "");
}
```

But this is still very inefficient approach, because `String` in java is **immutable**. It is much better to build another string using `StringBuilder`:

```java
public static String removeCharacters(String str, char ch) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i) != ch)
            buf.append(str.charAt(i));

    return buf.toString();
}
```